# Converting Flask validation errors to JSON

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask as my backend to create user accounts through an iOS application.  I can successfully create accounts, but I'm not too sure how I'm suppose to return the validation errors I get when username/email are already in use.  I'm thinking that when the form gets validated, it should return a dictionary of possible errors that gets converted to JSON and sent back to the app but not too sure how to approach this.

```
//form.py
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required()])
    password_hash = StringField('Password', validators=[Required()])

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            print("Email already registered.")
            raise ValidationError('Email already registered.')

    def validate_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first():
            print("Username already in use.")
            errorDict={'username': 'Username already in use.'}
            raise ValidationError('Username already in use.')
```

EDIT:
I modified the register function to test for various cases.  This is definitely not a good way of doing it, but its holding me over for now.

```
//userRegistration.py
@auth.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    try:
        data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
        form = RegistrationForm(data)

        if form.validate():
            user = User.register_fromJSON(request.json)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'success': 1})
        else:
            if form.email.errors and form.username.errors:
                print('case1')
                 return jsonify({'emailError': form.email.errors[0], 'usernameError': form.username.errors[0]})
            elif form.email.errors and not form.username.errors:
                print('case2')
                return jsonify({'emailError': form.email.errors[0]})
            elif form.username.errors and not form.email.errors:
                print('case3')
                return jsonify({'usernameError': form.username.errors[0]})

    except Exception:
        return jsonify({'Success': 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return jsonify({'Success': 0, 'Errors': 'invalid form'})
```

add in any specific validation errors you find. The app can then display them.

and it's a bad idea to use a bare `except Exception` clause - you are at least logging this, right?

you can use [Flask WTF](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/64/) to do the kind of validation you need

Comment: I guess i'm not sure how I would gather all the validation errors so that I could add them to jsonify.  The exception is just for logging right now.

Comment: I see that they're adding errors to a list by doing self.username.errors.append, but once you want to jsonify the errors, that list could vary from 1 error to 4 errors.  How would you write the jsonify line to account for a case when there is 1 error or a case when there are multiple errors?

Comment: `{'Success': 0, 'Errors': ['username taken', 'invalid email address']}`

Comment: what if the error is 'username does not meet requirements'. How do you determine which error to send back to the client?

Comment: Would something like `{'Success': 0, 'Errors': [form.username.errors, form.email.errors]}` work?

Comment: that entirely depends on what you want to do with that information at the client side

Comment: if the question solves your problem please accept it

Comment: I feel like it doesn't fully solve the issue.  Your answer shows how to return an error if there is only one error per field.  But what if username has one error because the length is too short and another error for inappropriate characters?  Since `form.username.errors` is a list, it could contain 1 error or multiple errors, so how would your write `jsonify` to return the correct number of errors per list?

Comment: this is a new requirement that wasn't mentioned in the original question - how about `{... 'errors': {'username': ['username already taken', 'invalid format'], 'email': ['invalid email address'],..}`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify in the original question.  Is errors a dictionary that contains a username dictionary and email dictionary?  My confusion in your solution is that you are just passing strings as errors.  the real errors are accessed by calling `form.username.error[0]`, which i'm doing at the moment.  However, form.username.error[0], form.username.error[1], and form.username.error[2] can all hold errors at the same time.  Since form.username.error is a list, whats the best way of checking how many errors it contains and how to set up `jsonify` to handle a varying number of errors?